# Domain: Windows 7 share, access denied from XP machine

Tags: windows, network-shares, domain

Have a Windows 7 share. There is a folder being shared out from that client. After a while, you can no longer access the computer from an XP client. Just says, "\client is not accessible". After rebooting the 7 box, it will work for a bit and then do the same thing.

Both clients are on a domain.

Any idea as to why this happens? The share works for a bit and then stops working on XP. Other 7 boxes can access the share still.

Thanks

Comment: How many total clients/users are accessing the share? Also, your title mentions "Access denied" yet the body of your question mentions (only) "client is not accessible".  What is the actual error your getting?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 When I check, there is only 1 other person connected. The error is pretty generic. The full error is "is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions. "

Comment: Hmm weird.  When it gets into that state, can you (still) ping the Windows 7 machine from the XP client?  Both by name and by IP address? If the share created via machine name, or IP address?  Have you confirmed that the XP machine has a proper and correct entry in the DNS server?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes. You can still get to it. Happens on all the XP boxes. Only 7+ can connect to it. As admin, I can't even connect to the hidden shares. Only way to resolve the issue is to reboot the windows 7 box, but not sure why it keeps doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A web search revealed this problem to be pretty old with dozens of references to the apparent solution. It seems that Alan LaMielle should get credit for [posting the solution first](http://alan.lamielle.net/2009/09/03/windows-7-nonpaged-pool-srv-error-2017).

### The Solution

First, make the following registry changes (on the Windows 7 'server'):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management]
"LargeSystemCache"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters]
"Size"=dword:00000003
```

Then, restart the server (or reboot):

```
net stop server
net start server
```

### About The Solution

In some other versions of Windows, there is an option in the Network section of Control Panel for optimizing the Server for file-sharing. In Windows 7, you have to make the registry changes yourself. Although Alan LaMielle helped many Windows 7 users figure this out, it had previously been described in Microsoft's [How to Optimize Windows NT Server Using the Registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232271):

> When you configure one of the four options for the Server service, the
>   information is saved to the following two registry keys:
>
> **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters\size**
>
> ```
> Your choices for this registry key are 1, 2 and 3.
>     1 = Minimize Memory Used
>     2 = Balance
>     3 = Maximize Throughput for File Sharing and Maximize
>         Throughput for Network Applications
> ```
>
> **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SessionManager\MemoryManagement\LargeSystemCache**
>
> ```
> Your choices for this registry key are 0 and 1.
>     1 = Maximize Throughput for File Sharing
>     0 = Maximize Throughput for Network Applications
> ```

[Answer source (SF.SE)](https://serverfault.com/a/236393/28311)

Comment: That was it. That's a pretty weird fix. Thanks!